# why my codepush cli active and total is 0

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I released my new version by code-push, then my app has installed new version successfully. When I use shell command "code-push deployment h myappname Staging" to checkout installation information about new version, the active and total still is 0, and 2 devices is pending(actually, they has installed successfully),[situation likes picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Phh.png).
Do you know why? Could you help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!
I have known why.
Because I forgot to invoke the api of `CodePush.notifyAppReady();`.
Please try it if you encounter the same question.